# How to enable short distance data transmission between two devices without BLE or infrared communication capabilities

Tags: wireless

I have two devices, neither of them have BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy) or infrared communication capabilities, but I would like to be able to transfer data between them over short distances. I know we have many wireless communication technologies to choose from, but in this case I seem to be stuck in a bit of a bind.

I'm trying to share some small files like photos and documents between these two devices, but I'm not sure how to accomplish this without traditional bluetooth, wifi, or infrared. Are there any other methods or devices that can help me achieve this? Maybe there is some special hardware or tricks I can use to establish short distance data transmission?

Comment: Sure, you can invent new communication methods. But. Why? You'd add communication capabilities either way, so wouldn't you prefer a standardized, tested, long-term available, cheap and easy solution? If not, then you need to explain in a lot more depth what you're ruling out, specifically, and why. Also "small" and "photo" seems to be quite opposing requirements.

Comment: Welcome to the forum.  We try to help answer specific questions, rather than broad topics, and your question as it stands is definitely broad.  To get a decent answer it would help if you edited your question to provide more details, such as: specific devices ideally including their ports, bandwidth you are looking to support (bytes or bits per second), reliability, etc.  In addition it would be good to explain why the technologies you already know exist do not provide solutions to your specific problem.

Comment: You did not say why you disregard BLE, WiFi and IR communication. There are other technologies like ZigBee, NFC and more. But as long as you don't share more details, it'll be difficult to answer your question properly.

Comment: Why is infrared a problem? Would you rather that people saw the light source? BTW infrared doesn’t need to imply slow speed remote-control-like communications. IRDA should work well for what you want to do. At least a standard to get you going.

Answer (score 1):

Back in 1999. at Maxim Integrated, I did some successful testing of a plain red laser pointer with a plain 5mm superbright (clear lens) red LED as a receiver. 
I simply hooked up the laser pointer's battery contacts to a signal generator, while the LED was connected directly to an oscilloscope to view the signal (LEDs can produce voltage when you shine the light of their color/wavelength at them). 
Without any additional circuitry, I was able to reach 11MHz before the signal became barely recognizable. I might have reached higher frequency if I did some modification. 
I suspect the LED's high output impedance, its own capacitance and the scope's input capacitance limited the highest frequency. It is possible the signal generator itself couldn't provide sufficient current at higher frequencies.

You could use an adapted laser diode driver to send digital bits via laser beam. 
If you connect the LED to a CMOS Shmitt triger input, you could get a clean digital output. 
I haven't done more experimenting with this, so I can't tell you more at this time. 
I do intend to do a few more additional tests ASAP. 
You do need to make sure the laser beam is aimed well at the LED and is stable (not moving around).